# Odd behavior of Static Variable of JavaScript closure programming

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

Why is this JavaScript code produce this funny result? Look at the RowID and CellID.

```
Result: 
[R0C0]: Apple   [R1C1]: 400
[R2C0]: Google  [R3C1]: 700


    <html>
     <head>
      <script src="ClosureAccessStaticVariable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
      <div id="panelTable"></div>
      <script>
        function Table(dataRows){
        var rows = [];
        this.GetTable = function(){
            var table = $("<table>");
            $(rows).each(function(){
                table.append(this.GetRow());
            });
            return table;
        }
        function init(){
            $(dataRows).each(function(index){
                rows[index] = new TableRow(this);
            });
        }
        function TableRow(rowData){
            var cells = [];
            this.GetRow = function(){
                var row = $("<tr>");
                $(cells).each(function(){
                    row.append(this.GetCell());
                });
                return row;
            }
            function init(){
                var i=0;
                for(var cellName in rowData){
                    cells[i] = new TableCell(rowData[cellName]);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            function TableCell(text){
                this.GetCell = function(){
                    if(TableRow.ID == undefined)
                        TableRow.ID = 0;
                    if(TableCell.ID == undefined)
                        TableCell.ID = 0;

                    var rowId = TableRow.ID;
                    var cellId = TableCell.ID;
                    TableRow.ID = TableRow.ID + 1;
                    TableCell.ID = TableCell.ID + 1;
                    return $("<td style='border:1px solid lightgray;padding:2px;'>").html("[R"+rowId+"C"+cellId+"]: "+text);
                }
            }
            init();
        }
        init();
        }
        var data = [ { Name: "Apple", Value: 400}, {Name: "Google", Value: 700}];
        var table = new Table(data);
        var tableDom = table.GetTable();
        $("#panelTable").append(tableDom);
    </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you put this in a jsFiddle? A wall of code is just not that fun to debug. How can we guess what's in ClosureAccessStaticVariable.js??

Comment: Why do you think the result is funny? What else had you expected?

Comment: Frenchie: What's in ClosureAccessStaticVariable.js is this code, just make it a html page so you can just run it as .html file.

Comment: Bergi: It is funny because there is a concept of static variable to the class, but the classes in JavaScript can be defined multiple times. I expected it behave as OOP concept, but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You're incrementing the row in every cell:

```
this.GetCell = function(){
    var rowId = TableRow.ID;
    var cellId = TableCell.ID;
    // The row ID gets updated 
    TableRow.ID = TableRow.ID + 1;
    TableCell.ID = TableCell.ID + 1;
```

Comment: You are right on the Row ID. But look at the Cell ID, supposedly the Cell ID would also be incremented every time. supposedly static variable belongs to the class. The answer I'm trying to get is why wouldn't Cell ID incremented, rather it reset for the second row. One main reason I can think of is because I created two TableRows objects, which the TableCell class get created again.